# Como accedo a un diccionario de una funcion diferente Python

Tags: python, api, diccionarios

Estoy intentando ocupar un diccionario generado desde una funcion ya generada. Para luego ocupar ese diccionario en otra funcion. En pocas palabras como lo llamo para acceder y aplicar cierta logica.

Codigo Funcion 1, que contiene los diccionarios:

```
def get_service():

    try:

       r = ## CAPTURO/CONSUMO SERVICIO DESDE UNA API ##

       dict_aux_idds = {
           'idd': [],
           'id': []
       }

       for i in r:

           if i["idd"] == '':
               dict_aux_idds['idd'].append([i["idd"]])
               dict_aux_idds['id'].append(i["id"])

          else:
              dict_aux_idds['idd'].append([i["idd"]])
              dict_aux_idds['id'].append(i["id"])

       dict_ = {'id': [], 'idd': []}
       for idx, val in enumerate(r):
           substring = val['idd']
           idd_list = [i for i in substring.split(',')]
           for el in idd_list:
               dict_['id'].append(val['id'])
               dict_['idd'].append(el)
    
    return dict_['idd'], dict_['id']

   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')
```

Codigo funcion 2, ocupando dict_['idd']:

```
get_service()
if ult_digitos in get_service.dict_['idd']:
                            
   index_ult_digitos = get_service.dict_['idd'].index(ult_digitos)
   final_id = get_service.dict_['id'][index_ult_digitos]
   print("PARAMETROS ENCONTRADOS!")
```

Como pueden notar, el parametro 'get_service.dict_['idd']' esta mal, lo que quiero lograr es poder acceder a ese diccionario simplemente para luego aplicar la logica en la funcion 2... Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Si te das cuenta, la función `get_service` retorna el diccionario que deseas utilizar, podrías hacer `get_service()[0]` para utilizarlo. Es decir `if ult_digitos in get_service()[0]:`

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ya pude resolverla amigo, gracias de todas formas. Publique la respuesta.

Comment: Muy bien, por favor agrega una explicación del por qué funciona como lo hiciste y acepta tu propia respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Ya lo hice

Comment: La respuesta aún no está aceptada y aún no tiene detalles suficientes

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre haciendo lo siguiente:

```
new_dict = get_service()
if ult_digitos in new_dict['idd']:
index_ult_digitos = new_dict['idd'].index(ult_digitos)
final_id = new_dict['id'][index_ult_digitos]
```